Databricks CLI (databricks api get <path>) prefixing stuff to path being queried in git-bash
I'm trying to list clusters using databricks cli's api subcommand. I know clusters can be listed using databricks clusters list, but this is about problem with the api subcommand as this is happening with every call and not just /clusters/list.
When I run databricks api get /api/2.0/clusters/list --debug I see that somehow the path argument gets prefixed with C:/ProgFiles/Git/
See this line debug log:
args="C:\\Users\\kash\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WinGet\\Packages\\Databricks.DatabricksCLI_Microsoft.Winget.Source_8wekyb3d8bbwe\\databricks.exe, api, get, C:/ProgFiles/Git/api/2.0/clusters/list, --debug"

I'm running this in git-bash that came with my git installation on Windows 10.
If I switch to Windows command prompt (cmd), it works fine.
Happens for all api calls, not just /clusters/list
Tried api version 2.1 as well, same thing.

~ $ set -x
~ $ databricks api get /api/2.0/clusters/list --debug
+ /c/Users/kash/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WinGet/Packages/Databricks.DatabricksCLI_Microsoft.Winget.Source_8wekyb3d8bbwe/databricks api get /api/2.0/clusters/list --debug
12:15:59  INFO start pid=30348 version=0.221.1 args="C:\\Users\\kash\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WinGet\\Packages\\Databricks.DatabricksCLI_Microsoft.Winget.Source_8wekyb3d8bbwe\\databricks.exe, api, get, C:/ProgFiles/Git/api/2.0/clusters/list, --debug"
12:15:59 DEBUG Loading DEFAULT profile from C:\Users\kash/.databrickscfg pid=30348 sdk=true
12:16:00 DEBUG GET /ProgFiles/Git/api/2.0/clusters/list
< HTTP/2.0 404 Not Found (Error: ) pid=30348 sdk=true
12:16:00 DEBUG non-retriable error:  pid=30348 sdk=true
Error:
12:16:00 ERROR failed execution pid=30348 exit_code=1 error=

~ $

~ $ databricks --version
Databricks CLI v0.221.1

~ $ bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.2.15(1)-release (x86_64-pc-msys)
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc...... snip ...

~ $
~ $ alias | grep ProgFiles
alias sl='/c/ProgFiles/ST3/subl'

~ $
~ $ ps
      PID    PPID    PGID     WINPID   TTY         UID    STIME COMMAND
     1208       1    1208      22332  ?       4289827476   Sep 12 /usr/bin/mintty
     1209    1208    1209      14008  pty0    4289827476   Sep 12 /usr/bin/bash
     2685    1209    2685       9276  pty0    4289827476 12:18:28 /usr/bin/ps

~ $
~ $ env | grep ProgFiles
PyCharm Community Edition=C:\ProgFiles\PyCharm\bin;
JAVA_HOME=C:\ProgFiles\jdk8.401
ORIGINAL_PATH=/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/kash/bin:/c/ProgFiles/VMware/bin:/c/ProgFiles/Python310/Scripts:/c/ProgFiles/Python310:/c/WINDOWS/system32:/c/WINDOWS:/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH:/c/Program Files/dotnet:/c/ProgFiles/WinSCP:/c/ProgFiles/Perforce:/cmd:/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/c/ProgFiles/jdk8.401/bin:/c/ProgFiles/AWSCLIV2:/c/Users/kash/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/c/ProgFiles/PyCharm/bin:/c/Users/kash/AppData/Roaming/Python/Scripts:/c/ProgFiles/VSCode/bin:/c/ProgFiles/poetry/bin:/c/My/workspaces/dlh-databricks/fxc/.venv/Lib/site-packages/pyspark/bin:/c/Users/kash/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WinGet/Packages/Databricks.DatabricksCLI_Microsoft.Winget.Source_8wekyb3d8bbwe
EXEPATH=C:\ProgFiles\Git
PATH=/opt/pmd-bin-6.15.0/bin:/opt/pycharm-community-2018.1.4/bin:/c/ProgFiles/BeyondCompare4:/c/My/workspaces/my_stuff/scripts:/c/Users/kash/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/c/ProgFiles/VMware/bin:/c/ProgFiles/Python310/Scripts:/c/ProgFiles/Python310:/c/WINDOWS/system32:/c/WINDOWS:/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH:/c/Program Files/dotnet:/c/ProgFiles/WinSCP:/c/ProgFiles/Perforce:/cmd:/c/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/c/ProgFiles/jdk8.401/bin:/c/ProgFiles/AWSCLIV2:/c/Users/kash/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/c/ProgFiles/PyCharm/bin:/c/Users/kash/AppData/Roaming/Python/Scripts:/c/ProgFiles/VSCode/bin:/c/ProgFiles/poetry/bin:/c/My/workspaces/dlh-databricks/fxc/.venv/Lib/site-packages/pyspark/bin:/c/Users/kash/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WinGet/Packages/Databricks.DatabricksCLI_Microsoft.Winget.Source_8wekyb3d8bbwe:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:C:\My\workspaces\dlh-databricks\fxc\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pyspark/bin

~ $ unset EXEPATH  # unsetting EXEPATH has no effect, same error

~ $ 

Any help is appreciated.
